# QEMU internet through bridged interface?

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, virtualization, network-bridge

I've recently setup QEMU on my server for learning/experimenting with virtualization.

I decided to use a bridge network setup so that the VM would appear on the local network and be visible from external networks.

I followed some steps I found on the Arch Wiki:

- [Network bridge with iproute2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_bridge#With_iproute2)
- [QEMU: Bridged networking](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU#Bridged_networking_using_qemu-bridge-helper)

After following these steps, the VM uses the bridge interface and is visible on my internal network. However, from inside the VM I cannot connect to any external sources (e.g., run an updater) without it throwing errors (not being able to resolve host names) or hanging.

Server OS: Ubuntu 16.04
VM OS: OpenBSD 6.1

If there's any other information I could provide, just let me know and I get it.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title. When you can, mark your answer as accepted to indicate that the question is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to enable NAT: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/QEMU#Host_configuration

I also stopped using QEMU's network bridge helper and manually set up a TAP interface.

After enabled NAT, allowing IP Forwarding with sysctl, allowing ARP proxy, and reinstalled OpenBSD in the VM, it works!